# How do I print elements in an ArrayList without the null?

Tags: arraylist, java

This is what I tried doing..

```
    public void printArray()
    {
         for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
         {

             System.out.println("arr[" + i + "] = " + arr[i]);

         }       
     }
```

this is what I get:

```
-arr[0] = Papa Bill
-arr[1] = Ali Baba
-arr[2] = Ming the Merciless
-arr[3] = Grandpa
-arr[4] = Tornado
-arr[5] = null
```

I need it to print with out null...

Comment: Pick up a Java textbook and read up on the `if` statement.

Comment: `if (arr[i] == null) continue;`

Comment: What @amit said, or more cleanly `if(arr[i] != null) System.out.println(...);`; add braces if you prefer

Answer (score 3):

Just add a check for null in your for loop:

```
if ( arr[i] != null ){
    System.out.println("arr[" + i + "] = " + arr[i]);
}
```